# Need direction on jQuery style of coding

Tags: jquery, coding-style

I posted a question asking if there was a way to consolidate the initialization of typeahead.js + Bloodhound controls here: [Can multiple inputs each using typeahead.js with different sources be consolidated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981411/can-multiple-inputs-each-using-typeahead-js-with-different-sources-be-consolidat).

I have around 10 inputs on a single page that will be typeahead-enabled and it seemed like that was going to call for a lot of somewhat repetitive code.

I came up with a "solution" of sorts that I posted as an answer, and it works - configuring another input was easy.  But I realized that I had fallen into the old Microsoft MFC function call style of having a lot of parameters that you may or may not need along with no clear indication of what the parameters are, betraying my 30+ year career as a Visual C++ programmer

I've read through most of the documentation here: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/ but I still don't feel like I have a good sense of the best way to address my question.

All of the sample code I've seen contains only one typeahead element, but what is a good approach in the "real world" when you have a page with multiple typeahead elements or any other similar control that requires significant configuration?

I'm new to jQuery and would like to apply generally accepted practices as much as possible, so tips or reading suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can include `html` , `js` at Question ?

Comment: Can you please post some of your code so people can see what you need and maybe be more specific with that you need?

Comment: My original question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981411/can-multiple-inputs-each-using-typeahead-js-with-different-sources-be-consolidat) contained a sample of the "standard" way of initialized typeahead/bloodhound along with a solution that I came up with.

Comment: What I'm asking is for a "real-world" approach to setting up 5 or more separate typeahead/bloodhound elements on a single page. Do devs simply take what I called the "standard" approach?  Is there a "template" approach better than what I came up with? I have not found any sample code that contains more than one instance of typeahead/bloodhound. Thanks for any help on this.